# Jquery each() fallback if no result found

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a JSON object on form submit to pass to Perl.
I have several nested `div`s with `ul`s an `li`s to allow a jQuery-ui sortable sorting.

To be able to save the sorted `li`s (which spread over several `div`s) I wrote the following code:

```
jQuery("form[name='editorview']").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var values = '{ ';
    jQuery(this).find(".div_abcd").each(function(){
        values += '"'+this.id+'": [';
        jQuery(this).find("div[id^='CONT']").each(function(){
            values += '{"'+this.id+'": [';
            jQuery(this).find("li").each(function(){
                if (jQuery(this).not("class='placeholder'")){
                    values += '"'+this.id+'",';
                } else {
                    values +='"placeholder",';
                }
            });
            values = values.slice(0, -1); //removing trailing ,
            values +=']},';
        });
        values = values.slice(0, -1); //removing trailing ,
        values += '],';
    });
    values = values.slice(0, -1); //removing trailing ,
    values += '}';
    jQuery("#order").val(values);
    document.editorview.submit();
});
```

There is a maximum of 4 `div`s with the class `div_abcd` but they don't necessarily include other `div`s. In this case I have the problem that the second  `values = values.slice(0, -1);` removes the opening `[` from line 5.

Is there any way to have an `else` if `jQuery(this).find("div[id^='CONT']").each(function(){` doesn't match anything. I tried to use `.not()` but it did not work.

**Edit:**

Even if my problem is solved, I would still like to know if there is a possibility to know when the each() does not run through even once.

**2nd Edit:**

Everything clear now. Thanks.

Comment: I think a better method would be to push the values to an array, then `join(',')` when done so you don't have to worry about trailing commas. Or do what Felix suggests :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet there is a better way than looping but for a start: Don't build the string manually!

```
var values = {};
jQuery(".div_abcd", this).each(function(){
    var a = values[this.id] = [];
    jQuery("div[id^='CONT']", this).each(function(){
        var obj = {};
        obj[this.id] = jQuery("li", this).map(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).is(".placeholder")){
                return "placeholder";                  
            }
            return this.id;
        }).get();
        a.push(obj);
    });
});
values = JSON.stringify(values);
```

**Update:** You also have to use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead of `not()`

**Reference:** [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), [`JSON`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=es3.1%3ajson_support)

Check this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/WNPjG/).

**Update** to answer your question:

You can always check how many elements are selected using [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/):

```
var $elements = jQuery(this).find("div[id^='CONT']");
if($elements.length > 0) {
    $elements.each(...);
}
else {
    // something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks this does the same job as my manually build string AND it fixes my problem. I would however still like to know if there is a possibility to know when the each() does not run through even once.

Comment: Well I would accept your answer twice if I could. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Pit: You're welcome :) Happy coding (and Happy New Year (soon;)))!

Answer (score 1):

you can get the results into a variable and check the length of the results. If it is not empty, you can do the loop or else you can skip the trimming.

Comment: You mean a variable I set inside of the each() loop, which would not be set if I don't enter the loop. And the trimming would be done in an if where I check if the variable is set? It should work, but I thought there was a more proper way of doing it